# Iterate the map and pass the value in method Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have to iterate over this details array and pass the id, name & designation to the method.

```
interface State {
  details: Array<{
    id: string;
    name: string;
designation: string;
  }>;
```

Method:

```
sampleItem = () => {
    this.sampleService
      .sampleMethod(
        this.props.id,
        this.props.name,
        this.props.designation
      )
      .then((response) => {
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    };
```

Instead of this.props.id, this.props.name, this.props.designation. I want to pass the values in it by iterating the details array. Can anyone please know how to do that! I tried doing it by writing the map function inside the method itself, but it is iterating number of times the value present in array:

```
sampleItemOne = () => {
    this.state.details.map((item) => {
     if(item) {
    this.productService
      .publishProduct(
        item.id,
        item.name,
        item.designation
      )
      .then((response) => {      
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information like from where you're trying to call this method and how are you accessing state information?

Comment: i am trying to call the method from the table. So in the table i have various rows

Comment: That's why it is calling multiple times same as the number of rows. You need to call this method outside the table as I think this method will feed data to your table to render rows right?

Comment: I cannot keep the method outside the table!because that functionality needs to be perform inside the table.

Comment: Then I guess you need to provide more context about the files, as we cannot help without seeing the code that what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What I am asking in the question is, how I'll get the id, name & designation iterating from the array & passing to my sampleItemOne method. If you can help me that, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but here is a try:

```
sampleItem = (id, name, designation) => {
    this.sampleService
      .sampleMethod(id, name,designation)
      .then((response) => {
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    };
```

And somehwhere else, you want to do this:

```
this.state.details.map(item => this.sampleItem(item,id, item.name, item.designation))
```